# How can I deactivate Google Voice on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-voice

I have iPhone 5 and Verizon service.

I used to have [Google Voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Voice) number but I haven't used it for 3 years and its no longer active. Couple of months ago I noticed a tone every time I dial a number to call out on my cell phone. My calls would then drop after couple of minutes in conversation with the person I was calling which is beyond annoying. Went to Verizon store, they changed my sim card, which did absolutely nothing.

Yesterday finally after a tone, I got an automatic message that the "Google Voice is ready to connect my call".

I deleted Google Voice app from my iPhone, and its still happening. I looked for settings all over the place and I have no idea how to deactivate this unwanted feature. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to deactivate the service by logging into the account via your computer. Refer to the following: https://support.google.com/voice/answer/2527649?hl=en

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work for AT&T so it may no longer work for Verizon. I just did this yesterday (28 Nov 2017). [Remove Google voice from iPhone](https://stevekinzey.blogspot.com/2017/11/remove-google-voice-from-your-iphone.html).